# Puppet: Error 400 Could not find any files

Tags: puppet

I double checked all settings but did not find the issue and that's why I try to get help here.

Let me show the configuration:

puppet.conf:

```
[...]
[master]
environmentpath     = $confdir/environments/
hiera_config        = $confdir/environments/production/sites/xy/config/hiera.yaml
default_manifest    = ./sites/xy/config/
environment_timeout = 0
```

fileserver.conf:

```
[...]
[sites]
   path /etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/
   allow *
```

auth.conf:

```
[...]
# extra mountpoint
path /sites
allow *
[...]
```

Now whenever I run Puppet and it tries to implement a specific file I get this:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find any files from puppet:///sites/xy/files/xy/xy.key.pub at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/xy/manifests/xy.pp:88 on node xy
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Note that I had to replace sensitive information by xy but for debugging purposes I try to give every detail where possible.
So `/sites` points to `/etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/` according to `fileserver.conf` and the directory exists like this (with correct permissions imho):

```
/etc/puppet % ls -ld /etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root puppet 4096 Oct  7 12:46 /etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/
```

The mentioned file `puppet:///sites/xy/files/xy/xy.key.pub` should therefore be located in `/etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/xy/files/xy/xy.key.pub` which looks like this:

```
/etc/puppet % ls -l /etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/*/files/*/*.key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root puppet 725 Oct  7 12:46 /etc/puppet/environments/production/sites/xy/files/xy/xy.key.pub
```

And the in the error message mentioned line 88 of the module which loads the file it looks like this:

```
$sshpubkey = file("puppet:///${sitefiles}/xy/${s0_pubkey}")
```

where `$s0_pubkey` is `xy.key.pub` and `${sitefiles}` is `sites/$site/files` which leads to the evaluated path of the requested file like this: `puppet:///sites/xy/files/xy/xy.key.pub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `file()` in Puppet can not handle Puppet mountpoints with `puppet://`. The official docs at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#file don't mention it specifically but obviously without mentioning it it means it can't handle extra mountpoints and wants to load files from a modules files directory.

My solution: I will use a variable which declares the absolute path to my "sites files" like this: `$sitefiles_absolute = "/etc/puppet/environments/${environment}/sites/xy/files/"` which will never change or at least not very often. And with keeping it in the `site.pp` file it can be used on every node and module.

Comment: This is not what actually went wrong. Would you like us to help solve your problem for you, or are you happy with the workaround?

Comment: Please go ahead with a better solution :) @MattSchuchard I would appreciate it to know the correct reason.

Comment: I was actually hoping John Bollinger etc. would do it because it requires a somewhat lengthy explanation and I am feeling lazy on vacation. I can revisit this in a few days.

Comment: So I will wait. Thanks.

Comment: Any news @MattSchuchard maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about this. So when you say 'Puppet mountpoints' in the answer, are you really referring to the Puppet URI, or is this some LVM you created?

Comment: When I say Puppet mointpoints then I mean the Puppet moint points of fileserver.conf configuration, @MattSchuchard.

Comment: Any news, @MattSchuchard ?

Comment: Nothing, @MattSchuchard ?

Comment: @MattSchuchard ? Maybe any more inputs?